# Column doesn't exist in android database

Tags: android, database

In my application I created a database and I tried to insert values into that table. But I received the following error:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table income has no column named recurrence: , while compiling: INSERT INTO income(recurrence, salary, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
```

My code is:

Database creation:

```
"create table income(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+"salary text not null,description text not null,"+"recurrence text not null);";
```

My insert query:

```
public long insertTitle(String income, String desc,String recurr)
{
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(KEY_INCOME, income);
initialValues.put(KEY_DESC, desc);
initialValues.put(KEY_RECURR, recurr);
//initialValues.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: You probably created the table with that property missing. You should also post the code where you create the DB schema.

Comment: I have added that table creation code also in above question.

Comment: Uninstall the app and then run it again.

Comment: I agree with Luksprog, try un- and reinstalling the app. Or increment the version number of the database in your Helper class if you wrote its update callback correctly.

Comment: ya i tried by cleaning  and ran the project,shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear your database form Android device. Maybe you application not overwriting the new database and using the old database. This may be a reason for this error.

Comment: If you are using device then just uninstall you application. and in emulator you can delete database using file manager from database folder.

Comment: Are you sure that your database is creating correctly?? Have you tried to use SQLLite manager to see your database?

Comment: ya  Vipul Purohit.. Y because b4  i have only salary and description field in my table,it works fine.When i tried to insert 1 new field(Recurrence) it shows this error.

Comment: Your Sql Query is absolutely fine. I think you new database is not overwriting on old database.

Comment: Ya Vipul Purohit.Now i tried in new device (installing 1st time in that device),in that device its works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where it is going wrong but i suggest you go and check your database using `adb`.
use following steps.

1. Open command prompt
2. Navigate to your android sdk folder-> platform tools
3. `adb -e shell`
4. cd data/data/your.package.name/databases
5. sqlite3 YOUR_DATABASE.db
6. Now run `.tables` or `.schema income` command
    OR  `select * from income;`

you will get idea if your table has been created or not.

you can also write dummy insert command to check if it is working properly.

```
Insert into income values(1,"salary","desc","rec");
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a '+' sign:

Put this one and try:

```
"create table income(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+"salary text not null,"+"description text not null,"+"recurrence text not null);";
```

And dont forget to Clear Data of your application before running.